# formatting the text output of HTML form (text that is sent in the email)

Tags: html, forms

I have a pretty ordinary HTML form that a convent uses for selling product. There are two things I'd like to do:

1. Stylize the text in the email they receive from the form submissions. Right now it's too close together, etc.
2. Make it so that the "unused fields" don't get included in the email. Example, the form lists all 8-12 products and there is a field for typing in the quantity the customer wishes to purchase. ALL 8-12 products get included in the email, and these 90+ year old ladies have a hard time seeing which one(s) have a quantity next to them.

This is "old school" I know, and if there's a better solution I'd love to hear it but these are ancient and wonderful ladies who are managing this business themselves so I want to be as low tech and simple as possible.

Then form is at https://blesacrament.org/altarbreads.php and the form processor is https://blesacrament.org/submit-form.php

Thank you for any tips you might have!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I included the URL of the form plus the URL of the processor thinking it was more practical to navigate and view source. Is that not right?